# BLE GATT in UWP application : Problem with async functions

Tags: c#, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I'm working on UWP Application to manage a BLE / GATT device.
I'm following the official documentation from Microsoft (https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/gatt-client). But I have a problem with the async function from BluetoothLEDevice class.

When I write the following line :

```
BluetoothLEDevice bluetoothLeDevice = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceInfo.Id);
```

I have the followings errors :

- Error    CS0012  The type 'IAsyncAction' is defined in an assembly that
  is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Windows,
  Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null,
  ContentType=WindowsRuntime'.
- Error    CS0012  The type 'IAsyncActionWithProgress<>' is defined in an
  assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
  'Windows, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral,
  PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime'.
- Error    CS0012  The type 'IAsyncOperation<>' is defined in an assembly
  that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
  'Windows, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral,
  PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime'.
- Error    CS0012  The type 'IAsyncOperationWithProgress<,>' is defined in
  an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to
  assembly 'Windows, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral,
  PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime'.

[image: Because sometimes, it is more readable]

I tried to add manually the following reference (Like I found in multiple post) :

C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\system.runtime.windowsruntime.dll

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\Windows.winmd

But, in the first case, VS saying it is already including by the generator system (or someting like this). And in the 2nd case, I have many class in my code that are referenced twice (Like Page for example)

What is the solution ?

Comment: A [screenshot of an error](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) in french is not helpful for most readers. It would help if you translated the exception message and added it as text

Comment: For sure ! Mistake is corrected ! But I keep the screenshot (in english now), because, sometimes, it is more readable than the message list ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you lack references to the UWP api that is needed to use it in .Net applications.

Make sure you are using [Package References](https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files) in your project and you have added [Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts as a nuget package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance)

Comment: Yes ! That 's was the  problem !!! Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts is missing ! thanks a lot !

Comment: But now, I have an error only at compilation : Error CS1704 An assembly with the same simple name 'Windows.Services.Store.StoreContract' has already been imported. Try removing one of the references (e.g. '%user%\.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.Services.Store.StoreContract.winmd') or sign them to enable side-by-side.

Comment: This is probably because you ttried to add the references manually in your earlier attempts. Try remove any references other than the nuget package.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer, but it is easier than this ! Nuget package is SDK 10.0.18362 and my app was designed for a 10.0.16299 target ! I just change target to 18362, and now it's ok !